# What is the quickest way to kill Camel Zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

Throughout the Egypt location, there are often zombies that come in sets of 3:

[image]

Assuming no other zombies are a concern and no plant food is used, what plant or plant combination will defeat them the quickest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since they come in sets of three, the Bloomerang does quite well; it hits all 3 parts of the camel and then all 3 of the zombies after breaking the screens, and it does so *twice*. Bloomerangs are less effective if there is another zombie in the way though, since they will only hit up to 3 zombies before returning.

I haven't gotten very far so I can't speak for the other plants, but you'll have the Bloomerang before you start seeing the camel zombies, so they're a solid early game choice. Logically speaking, any plants that penetrate or deal area of effect damage should do similarly well; the risk with these zombies is if you only damage the front they can easily overwhelm light or modest defenses.

Comment: Great answer.  And you helped me understand why sometimes the Bloomerang attack goes all the way across the screen and other times not so far.  Thanks!

Comment: snapdragon is my go to plant for just about everything in pvz2.

Answer (score 2):

1. A good attack - only option is Lightning Reed. It attacks multiple plants at once. It's [pretty weak on its own](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141642/can-a-single-lightning-reed-kill-3-camel-zombies/141650?noredirect=1#141650) but 2 of them should take care of the trio without a problem - WHILE attacking other neighboring zombies.
2. Also, while this isn't a straight up "attack" answer (for that see @Ben Brocka's good one, or #1 in mine), but a good combination to defeat the camel zombie is with Iceberg Lettuce + some other attack plant.

   This works (and is special enough to mention as a separate answer) because when the front zombie in the camel triplet steps on an iceberg lettuce, **all 3 zombies in a trio freeze!**

   This slows them down enough that lighter attack plants (2 pea shooters or a repeater) can handle them easily.

Answer (score 1):

Imo the best against it is bloomerang with bonk choy paired with a walnut guarding it. None will pass.

Comment: [You Shall Not Pass](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouShallNotPass)