# Can a single Lightning Reed kill 3 camel zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

I was answering [this Q](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129028/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-kill-camel-zombies/141641#141641), and proposed 2 Lightning Reeds as a way to kill 3 Camel Zombies.

However, I'm unsure if they can be killed by just 1 Lighting Reed (with no other plants).

**So, if we have a Lightning Reed on leftmost square, and 3 camel zombies coming at it, will it be able to kill all 3 alone?**

No other plants, no other zombies, no plant food.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously doubt it.

Lightning reeds do about [half damage](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Reed#Trivia) compared to a peashooter.  Camel zombies have [twice the hitpoints](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Camel_Zombies) of basic zombies.  In my experience, an unimpeded basic zombie travels a little over 3 squares in the time it takes a peashooter to kill it.

So, a basic zombie should be able to travel around 6 squares while taking damage from a single lightning reed, and a camel zombie should be able to travel at least 12 squares while taking damage from a single lightning reed.  As there are only 9 squares in a column, I don't think the lightning reed will be able to defeat the camel zombies.